# How do I remove the oem logo shown during boot in ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption?

Tags: boot, encryption

I have removed the oem logo by configuring plymouth but it is still shown before I enter my password during boot and I can't find a solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The OEM logo comes from the bios in the system.  It remains on the screen during boot because Ubuntu has gone to great lengths to not clear it.

The easiest way to get rid of it is to replace it with something else.
You can modify the grub boot sequence to load your own image, or just force it to a text console (uncomment the `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` line in /etc/default/grub and rerun `update-grub`) so there is no image.

However, note that full disk encryption is already fragile, and adding an unsigned image to the boot process that includes full disk encryption is tricky and hazardous.   You might be better off forcing text mode or just leaving the OEM image.